# Can't seem to get jschr bootstrap-modal library to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I just wanted to get a feel for how the bootstrap-modal library works because I need to be able to use stacked modals on my page. However, I can't seem to get much more than the overlay to appear. Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>checkbox</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-modal.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css">

</head>
<button class="demo btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" href="#stack1">View Demo</button>
<div id="stack1" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3>Stack One</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <input type="text" data-tabindex="1">
    <input type="text" data-tabindex="2">
    <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#stack2">Launch modal</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="stack2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3>Stack Two</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <input type="text" data-tabindex="1">
    <input type="text" data-tabindex="2">
    <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#stack3">Launch modal</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="stack3" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3>Stack Three</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
    <input type="text" data-tabindex="1">
    <input type="text" data-tabindex="2">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-modal.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

I literally just copied and pasted from the demo site and tried to get this going and was planning on modifying it with my own content but I don't know what I'm missing. I have tried a script on the bottom:

```
<script>
    var modalManager = $("body").data("modalmanager");
    var openModals = modalManager.getOpenModals();
</script>
```

to see if I could get a reference to the modal manager but modalManager is undefined. I don't know if this is an issue with the order of the css and script tags or what. All of them are included in the same folder as the html page. I am using bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

remove selector `hide` and you don't need script, the stack modals will work, what causing modal not showing is selector `hide` as you are using bootstrap 3 and `hide` has `important` rule

```
.hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

and so remove it from `class="modal hide fade"` from all modals and stack modals will work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/css/bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/css/bootstrap-modal.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>
<script src="http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<button class="demo btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" href="#stack1">View Demo</button>
<div id="stack1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
         <h3>Stack One</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
        <p>One fine body…</p>
        <p>One fine body…</p>
        <input type="text" data-tabindex="1">
        <input type="text" data-tabindex="2">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#stack2">Launch modal</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="stack2" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
         <h3>Stack Two</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
        <p>One fine body…</p>
        <input type="text" data-tabindex="1">
        <input type="text" data-tabindex="2">
        <button class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#stack3">Launch modal</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="stack3" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-focus-on="input:first">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
         <h3>Stack Three</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
        <input type="text" data-tabindex="1">
        <input type="text" data-tabindex="2">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLnbma29/)

Comment: I should bring this up to the author of bootstrap-modal.js. His demo documentation is wrong then.

Comment: may be the documents are old not updated, `hide` selector used with modals in B.S-2 but removed in B.S-3